# Issue with gsub and str_replace_all in R

Tags: r

I need to replace 38 different types of expressions in the following format `"IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF", "IDENTIFIER:GHI:JKL"`, etc. with regular expressions like `"apple"` and `"banana"`. I've tried using str_replace_all in the following format:

```
    df$column <- df$column %>% str_replace_all("IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF", "apple")
    df$column <- df$column %>% str_replace_all("IDENTIFIER:GHI:JKL", "banana")
```

However, for some reason, R only processes about half of my requests. I've checked and double checked for errors and tried to break up the code but no success.

So then I tried the same with gsub:

```
    df$column <- gsub(df$column, "IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF", "apple") 
    df$column <- gsub(df$column, "IDENTIFIER:GHI:JKL", "banana")
```

and I get this error: "In gsub(df$column ...): argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

I'm really not sure what to do next. Any advice?

Comment: `gsub` need to be feed with pattern, replacement_values, and x. So, in your cases, you should write `gsub("IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF", "apple",df$column)` or `gsub(pattern = "IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF", replacement = "apple", x = df$column)`

Comment: Compare the docs for the two functions: their arguments aren't in the same order

Comment: Thanks @dc37 - that was the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsubfn` in the package of the same name provides a superset of `gsub` functionality and in particular it can optionally take a list as a replacement instead of a string.  For each match to the regular expression if the match equals one of the list names it is replaced with the corresponding list value.

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- "xyz IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF abc IDENTIFIER:GHI:JKL def" # test input
L <- list("IDENTIFIER:ABC:DEF" = "apple", "IDENTIFIER:GHI:JKL" = "banana")
gsubfn("\\y\\S+\\y", L, x)   
## [1] "xyz apple abc banana def"
```

This also works:

```
gsubfn("\\b\\S+\\b", L, x, perl = TRUE)   
## [1] "xyz apple abc banana def"
```